# Show value name select javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a select dropdown where I get data from an API, later I add the value of the item selected on a table. All works good but when I click in **addItem()** I add the id value of the item of the select, but I want to show the **name_value** instead of the **id** on the table. At the same time, I need to get the id value of the select item.

Select code (VUEJS):

```
 <select
        id="select1"
        ref="seleccionado"
        v-model="id_equipo"

        required
      >
        <option
          v-for="equipo in equipos"
          :key="equipo.id_equipo"
          :value="equipo.id_equipo"
        >
          {{ equipo.nombre_equipo }}
        </option>
      </select>
```

button addItem:

```
  <v-btn
        color="blue darken-1"
        @click="addItem()"
      >
        Aregar Equipo
      </v-btn>
```

table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr
      v-for="item in rowData"
      :key="item.id_torneo"
    >
      <td>{{ item.id_torneo }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.id_equipo }}</td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
```

function addItem:

```
  addItem () {
    var equipos_torneo = {
      id_torneo: this.id_torneo,
      id_equipo: this.id_equipo,
    }
    this.rowData.push(equipos_torneo)
  },
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex]` will return the currently chosen option. You can then extract it's label via `.textContent` or its value with `.value`
Choose the appropriate method for setting  `selectElement`. Perhaps `document.getElementById('select1')` will suffice for your needs. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way instead:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <!-- Your select code -->
      <select id="select1" ref="seleccionado" v-model="id_equipo" required>
        <option
          v-for="equipo in equipos"
          :key="equipo.id_equipo"
          :value="equipo.id_equipo"
        >
          {{ equipo.nombre_equipo }}
        </option>
      </select>

      <!-- Your button code -->
      <v-btn
        color="blue darken-1"
        @click="addItem()"
      >
        Aregar Equipo
      </v-btn>

      <!-- Your table code -->
      <tbody>
        <tr
          v-for="item in rowData"
          :key="item.id_torneo"
        >
          <td>{{ item.id_torneo }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.id_equipo }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
      addItem () {
        // Search the object in the equipos array with the selected id from the select
        let equipos_torneo = this.equipos.find(v.id_equipo === this.id_equipo);

        // If object gets found successfully, push to the rowData array
        if(equipos_torneo) this.rowData.push(equipos_torneo);
      },
    },
}
</script>
```